# Convert two-byte hex string to char in perl

Tags: perl, encoding, character-encoding

I have a string of two-byte hex characters and I'd like to convert them to an ascii or unicode string. The string can have a variable length. Input:

```
$hex_string="003400300030"
```

Desired output:

```
$char_string="400"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Encode qw( decode );

my $char_string = decode('UTF-16be', pack('H*', $hex_string));
```

Comment: @Borodin I know what to do. But the system didn't allowed me to mark as solved because it was too soon.